# A technical term to describe adjectives like "fast", "long", "strong", "large", "deep", "loud", etc

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, terminology

What is the technical term to describe adjectives like *fast*, *long*, *strong* that are used to describe a particular property of an object in relation to another object's?

Here is an example.

Let's say I have a 20-centimetre ruler.

1. I can say,

   > This ruler is *short*.

   as I compare it to a 1-meter ruler.
2. Or I can give the opposite statement as I compare it to my pen:

   > This ruler is *long*.

Both statements make sense. Whether it is *short* or *long* depends on what I am comparing it to.

(**Edit:** counterexamples would be *Christian, gravitational, electromagnetic, cosmic, cosmological*. These are adjectives, too. And I don't think they fit into the category.)

**So what is this type of adjectives technically called?**

I've come up with the phrase 'relative term', but after a check with [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_term), it doesn't seem to be the technical term I am looking for.

> A **relative term** is a term that makes two or more distinct references to objects (which may be the same object, for example in "The Morning Star is the Evening Star"). A relative term is typically expressed in ordinary language by means of a phrase with explicit or implicit blanks. Examples:
>   __ loves __
>   __ is the same object as __
>   __ is giver of __ to __.
>
> The word **is** is a relative term when it expresses identity. The colloquial meaning for a relative term is that > it is different for different people. An example: someone who is 5 feet tall might think someone who is 6 feet tall is tall, but someone who is 5 feet 5 inches would think that someone who is 6 feet 5 inches is tall.

Comment: "Relative term" seems to me like exactly the phrase that you want.  Can you clarify why you think it's not the right answer?

Comment: @David: it is indeed the right answer; see my answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The *Adjectives* article in [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjective#Types_of_use) mentions four kinds of use of adjectives; see the article for details, but (in brief) it refers to Attributive adjectives, Predicative adjectives, Absolute adjectives, and Nominal adjectives.  In your example "This ruler is long", *long* is being used as a nominal adjective, in spite of being a relative term.  Note, your question presupposes the adjectives in the examples are relative terms; that there is another object being compared to; but often the comparison is to a fixed set of things, and within that framework the comparison is absolute rather than relative.

Comment: No, in "this ruler is long", "long" is a *predicative* adjective. In a later section, the [same Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjective#Comparison_of_adjectives) says the kind of adjectives the OP is asking about are called *comparable* or *gradable*.

Answer (score 3):

As has been pointed out, most if not all adjectives presuppose a reference system whereby their appropriateness in describing a referent is judged.

Sometimes, this will call for a subjective decision - where does *green* end and *yellow* begin?

Classifying and 'singling out' adjectives such as *chemical*, *unique*, *solar* are inherently ungradable, but may still be contrasted with adjectives referring to related classes (*physical*; *lunar*).

Those terms which apply to a referent when viewed in one reference system, but not when viewed in others (such as short / long above) are **context-dependent** - a descriptor hardly confined to grammar, but very appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're thinking of a grammatical unit native to another language. I imagine some other languages can have a particular term.

But in English, the words that you cited are all just classified as "*adjectives*."

Relative properties start when we employ comparative and superlative forms of adjectives. But they're already different from what you want to identify. For example, *faster*, *longer*, *stronger* etc.

---

Words that you might find helpful are:

```
attribute 

property
```

But I have to tell you that they're not really limited to grammar terminology.

Comment: +1 Yes, you are correct. In my language there is a precise term to define these words.

Comment: In English, I think you can make any adjective into a relative adjective, even ones which you logically shouldn't be able to.  Consider the [grammatical arguments](http://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2008/01/justifiable-usage.html) about *more perfect, more unique, more just, more dead* (although note this last one isn't *deader*, which it should be if it followed the rules since *dead* is one-syllable).

Answer (score 1):

There has been an argument among English prescriptive grammarians about whether you should be able to use comparatives on adjectives like *perfect, just, dead, unique*. It seems that logically, they shouldn't be able to take comparatives<sup>1</sup>, but English speakers persist in using *more perfect*, *more just* and *juster* nevertheless.  Googling this set of adjectives, you find that they [have been called](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_%28grammar%29) *absolute* or *ungradable*. Adjectives not in this set would then be *relative* or *gradable*.

Since English speakers go ahead and apply comparatives to all adjectives, it isn't clear that this is a real grammatical class in English.

<sup>1</sup> If something isn't *perfect*, it has to be *imperfect*, so it can't be *less perfect*. Similarly, *unique* means there is only one of them. If there are two, it's no longer unique. And someone is either dead or alive; how can one person be *more dead* than another?

Comment: deader than a doornail

Comment: It is not true that all adjectives are gradable.

Comment: @Edwin: I would say that in English, *gradable* is not a grammatical class, but maybe a logical class. Nobody says *pink justice,* but that's because the concept doesn't make sense, and not because of any grammatical rule that *pink* cannot modify *justice.* There's no grammatical rule that color adjectives cannot modify abstract nouns. Similarly, nobody may say *more igneous*, but that's because the concept doesn't make sense, not because *more igneous* is an ungrammatical construction.

Comment: I'll rephrase my comment. There are some adjectives that no English speaker in his/her right mind (excepting maybe comedians) would "go ahead and apply comparatives to": classifying adjectives, such as chemical, solar....

Comment: @Edwin: I agree, although I don't think you chose the right examples; "more chemical" can occur naturally. In fact, found on the web: *"... or do you think that addiction is really more chemical in nature?"*

Comment: I'd say that "more" in "more chemical" in the example you give is part of an elision, say from "controlled more by chemical factors than by psychological ones", rather than a true modifier of the adjective (contrast "more violent"). This would follow the models 'fairer society' (society closer to being a fair one) and 'fairly unique' (fairly close to being unique). I consider elisions 1 and 3 here poor renderings; I suppose 'fairer society' is snappy and now accepted.

Comment: Among other semantically ungradable adjectives that are, however, treated as gradable are full, still, quiet, flat and well.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you’re looking for *scalar*, i.e., those adjectives that appeal to a conventionalized scale of measurement.  (The linguistics literature notes that ad hoc scales can be improvized for most adjectives; hence, the qualification “conventionalized”.)

Comment: *Scalar* incidentally refers to quantities that have 'only magnitude, not direction'., cf. *vector*; 'of or relating to a musical scale'; 'a variable quantity that cannot be resolved into components'.

Comment: @Kris _Scalar_ also has another meaning: ladderlike in arrangement or organization; graduated (Webster's) (though I also wish it hadn't).

Answer (score 0):

Modifiers of ***measurement***/ ***dimension*** adjectives
*small, large, short, long, old, new, cold, hot,* …

*The long hot Japanese summer*
- - -length- - - - - - - - - - - - - -
- - - - -temperature- - - - - - - -